# Adding multiple spritesheets in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have the following code to set up my spritesheets and batch node:

```
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"soldier-test.plist"];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"soldier-running.plist"];

    batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"soldier-test.png"];

    self.player = [Player spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"shooting s0000.bmp"];
    [batchNode addChild:self.player];

    [player setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];

    [self addChild:batchNode];
```

However, when I try to have player (a subclass of CCSprite) perform an action using frames from the second spritesheet, I get assertion errors related to the texture files. Do I need to combine the sheets into one, or is there a way to span one CCSprite over multiple spritesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SpriteBatchNode can only have children that all use the same texture. Your player needs to use the texture soldier-test.png if you want to add it to your batchNode.

With a TextureAtlas you can put multiple different textures into one big image.